# In which SE I should ask questions regarding the publication of fictional work? (Poems, songbooks, etc.)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to self-publish a book (Fictional; poem and songbook). I have a lot of questions regarding the publication of this.

But I cannot find an appropriate site! (the Academia site seems to be oriented toward scientific/research publications).

So where might I post such questions?

Answer (score 13):

I think https://writing.stackexchange.com/ is a good place to go. I'm not a frequenter of that site but [the tour page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) states:

> Writing Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for anybody interested in the craft of writing, editing, and **publishing**, whether it's professionally, artistically, or as a hobby.

[emphasis mine]

The [[publishing]](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag also states:

> It may refer to the commercial publishing industry, small press, **self-publishing** and on-demand publishing. This tag **should be used for any questions regarding the publishing process in any of these forms**.

[emphasis mine]

In their [help/on-topic](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> ***Questions on these topics are welcome here:***
>
> The publishing and editing process itself.

I also found a question about [publishing children's books](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18056/self-publishing-marketing-childrens-book) that is seeking advice and was received quite positively so I think you're safe to go there.

Make sure to always check a site's rules and guidelines before posting and ensure, to the best of your ability, that your post is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [writing Stack Exchange.](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) [Their help/on topic page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and other pages agree that your question is fine.
UPDATE:It seems that you have posted your question. Nice job and it seems to be recieved well.

Comment: +1'd and Thank you. I have found that site by reading comments and answers to my question at Meta. And I have asked 2 questions there yet.